# Same jQuery for each list item

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" 
            onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin', 'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); 
                return false;" >Go to Yahoo
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com" 
            onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin', 'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); 
                return false;" >Go to Facebook
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" 
            onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin', 'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); 
                return false;" >Go to Google
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to make that `onclick` jQuery apply to all list item? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to each of the `a` elements which need this functionality and then do:

```
$('a[href].yourClass').click(function(){
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'mywin', 'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

shouldjust add this...

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            window.open(link, 'mywin', 'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
});
```

you should add some class to your a's to make sure this won't apply to all links int you html ...

Answer (score 1):

You could add a listener on your `ul` thats listen on click from it sub `a`

```js
$('ul').on("click", "a", function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
    href = $this.attr("href");

  window.open(href, 'mywin', 'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Go to Yahoo</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Go to Facebook</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```